# Display only top 25% of block

Tags: css

I have certain generated shapes using css3. I want to display only some part of block eg: 25% of above or 25% of bottom. How do I achieve this?

eg: In http://jsfiddle.net/HNyHM/1/ ; I want to display only 25% from above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/LB8mC/

Wrap you CSS shape inside a div, give it the height, width exactly how much you want show the shape. Then position the shape absolutely with respect to the wrapper.

Here is what I have used in fiddle.

```
  .shape-wrapper {
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden
        height: 25px;
  }



  .shape-wrapper > div {
        top: -25px;
        left: -25px;
     }
```

You can keep on changing the position of child div (top 25% or bottom 25% like you were asking using JS.

Comment: you are simply moving the block using top:-25px and left: -25px. This wont work if the block is centered and not at any corners. Any other solution?

Comment: See instead of centering your shape, you'll then need to center your wrapper instead. And you can use % too instead of px for top and left. If you are still not getting it, give me a fiddle where you think it wont work & I will get it working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a wrapper div might help. See http://jsfiddle.net/HNyHM/3/ for a start with fixed sizes though.

Comment: +1 ... this looks good and very close to solution, but is it possible to display it in % because the height may vary?

Comment: Percentage is rather difficult here given the fact, that you rotate your :before and :after content. The real height of the figure has then to be calculated using (co)sine function.